# I want to create a Javascript that would eliminate the validation rules and save the page

Tags: javascript, skuid

I want to save the page by excluding validations and render conditions, its just so that I can comeback and edit the page later. Just like save in progress, so that I don't need to finish the form in one go.

I need java script to avoid validation rules, so that I can use that on a button and save the page. By the way I am using Skuid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation rules are processed server side (for good reason) so you cannot bypass them from the client. The closest you could get would be to add a checkbox to the object that if true causes all validation rules to pass. You could then set a hidden apex:input for this checkbox via JavaScript before the form gets submitted.